# Do I gain any speed boost if my PC is connected to a switch that has two different connections to my router?

Tags: networking

For my Internet connection, I use a DOCSIS cable modem with built-in WiFi router. On the other side of my room, I have a WiFi access point connected to the router's WiFi (blue dotted line = WiFi). Additionally, the WiFi AP is connected via LAN (black solid line = LAN) to a powerline AP with built-in LAN switch. My PC and NAS are also connected to the built-in switch of the powerline AP. My PC and NAS connect through the switch, through the WiFi AP to the WiFi router with the Internet. In addition to that, there is a second powerline AP with WiFi in the basement. The two powerline APs in my room and in the basement are connected via AC power lines (red dotted line = AC power lines). Different WiFi devices like smartphones therefore can also connect to the Internet from the basement.

[image: Current network diagram]

I am not concerned about the connection speed between the basement and my room. However, I would like the PC and NAS to be connected as fast as possible to the Internet. Unfortunately, I cannot connect them via LAN to the modem and the current bottleneck is the WiFi connection between the WiFi AP and the WiFi router. Even with 802.11ac and simultaneous smart cross-band communication over 2.4 and 5 GHz, I only get about 500 Mbit/s net rate. What I can do is add another powerline AP near the router and have it talk directly to the powerline AP my PC and NAS are connected to. Once this is set up, the WiFi AP serves no purpose any longer so it can be removed.

[image: Planned network diagram]

My question is: Would keeping the WiFi AP give me any speed boost? With it still in place, the powerline AP with built-in switch would theoretically be connected to the WiFi router via AC power line **and** via WiFi through the WiFi AP. Or is it?

Comment: I'm not so sure the WiFi is your bottleneck, but rather the powerline. If that's the case, you need to rethink your strategy. That said, you cannot really connect through 2 devices simultaneously. In Windows you can create a bridged adapter, but the other side must also support that, which usually is not the case. So connecting both basically means, sometimes one of the lines is chosen and the other is not, depending on which connects first or is set as preferred device in windows.

Comment: It's definitely the WiFi. The powerline connection currently only exists between my apartment in the 4th floor and the basement (1st picture). The PC and the NAS connection to the Internet runs through the powerline switch right into the WiFi AP and then over WiFi to the router / modem. The powerline switch is not limiting anything as transfers from my PC to the NAS run with 1 GBit/s (118 MB/s transfer rate, so barely a speed loss).

Comment: @smares looking at transfers between the PC and NAS doesn't tell you anything.  According to your diagram those transfers run on the LAN not via the power line so they will of course be fast.  To check if it's the power line or wifi that is the bottle neck you need devices on each side. Never used them personally but my understanding is the power line adapters can be quite slow.

Comment: What is it that you don't understand that there is no powerline connection between the PC and the Internet? The only reason for the powerline in the CURRENT (image 1) setup is to provide Internet to the basement for some smartphones when I am woodworking. And the only reason I mentioned the connection between the PC and the NAS is because the powerline adapter in my room has a built-in switch and I didn't want people to tell me that the switch is crap not being a dedicated one, that is why I mentioned that I get the full speed between PC and NAS through the built-in powerline switch.

Comment: @smares you're right, I didn't read things fully.  As you noted in your answer adding the extra connection likely wont give a speed boost by using both connections.  Depending on how good/bad your wifi/powerline adapters are you may or may not see a difference by switching the medium.  Testing wifi vs power line may be worthwhile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading some more about this matter, I am pretty certain there won't be any speed boost since only one connection will be used at a time. For what I had in mind, link aggregation is used, but none of my devices supports that.